# How to Create a Switch Topology Page using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i am developing a website about network i need your help..

Lets consider, i have 10 switch, in same brand (cisco 3560) in my LOCAL AREA NETWORK topology and all switches have management ip addresses, such as; 10.1.1.8,10.1.1.9...,

Requirements:

1. When default page is opened; The website will scan(discover) all active Switches and their managements ip addresses.
2. After discover operation is completed; it will bring (DRAW) switch images and their physical connections, into webpage like in packet tracer network program.
3. The platforms that i am using are, c#, asp.net, Visual Studio.

I don't know where to start! How to discover switches and how to find libraries to draw diagrams of discovered switches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use SNMP to detect network-connected devices that are managable.  There's limited built-in support for this in the BCL; I think 3rd party libraries may be a better route; like http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/